# Definition of linear independence when $v_i=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have read that linear independence occurs when:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i =0$$

Has only $a_i=0$ as a solution, but what if all $v_i$ were $0$ then $a_i$ could vary and still yield $0$. Does that mean that such a vector set is not linearly independent?

What if I have:

Let $\{c_0,c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n\}$ denote a set of $n+1$ distinct elements in $\mathbb{R}$. Define the set of $n+1$ polynomials.

$$f_j(x)=\prod_{k=0,k\ne j}^n \frac{x-c_k}{c_j - c_k} $$

Note that $f_j(x) \in P_n(\mathbb{R})$ with the property
$$f_j(c_l) = \left\{ \begin{align} 0&& \text{if}&& j\ne l\\ 1&& \text{if}&& j= l \end{align} \right.$$

And $\alpha = \{f_0(x),f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x)\}$, then this is or isn't linearly independent based on my $x$ value. Is there something here that forces $x$ to equal one of my $c_j$? For I am told that this $\alpha$ is linearly independent.

Comment: The named polynomials are independent. For, if $a_{0} f_{0}(x) + \dots + a_{n} f_{n}(x) = 0$, set $x = c_{i}$ to get $a_{i} = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Any set of vectors containing zero is linearly dependent, that is, *not* linearly independent.

This is simply because, as you have said, if $v_{1} = 0$, say, then
$$
1 \cdot v_{1} + 0 \cdot v_{2} + \dots + 0 \cdot v_{n} = 0,
$$
and not all coefficients are zero.

Comment: If you have time, could you please review my edit for clarification on my lack of understanding?

Comment: Should it be 
If $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i =0$ then $a_i=0 \forall x$
As a linear independence test?

Comment: @DisplayName, sure, but I have class now, will try later.

Comment: Still, $v_{1}, \dots, v_{n}$ are l.i. if the only solution of the equation $a_{1} v_{1} + \dots + a_{n} v_{n} = 0$ in the unknown $a_{i}$ is $a_{1} = \dots = a_{n} = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of linearly independent vectors the space $X$ itself is supposed to consist a non-zero vector $v$, thus not all of the $v_i$'s are zero vectors.

Answer (score 1):

If there exists such an $i$ for which $v_i=0$, then selecting $\alpha_i=1$ and $\alpha_j=0$ for $j\neq i$ means that $$\sum_{k=1}^na_kv_k=a_iv_i=0.$$

This means that if at least one vector in the set is $0$, the set is not linearly independent.